# Java string validation using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate an input string using regex.

The requirement is:

The input

1. must not start with `%`, `_`
2. must not contain `&`, `#`, `>`, `<`
3. may be empty

I have used `[^%_#&<>][^#&<>]*|^$` successfully.

Is there any better way to address the problem?

Comment: You could use look-around to avoid repeating some of the characters, but I think your current solution is elegant enough. Are you not happy with it?

Comment: Your regex matches `%a` and `a#`

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a regex? `startsWith()` and `contains()` seems easier for this use case.

Comment: @Stewart: I guess using a regex will be faster, since contains should run several times whereas a regex checks all constraints during the same run. Furthermore a regex is easy to modify, maintain,... whereas a program is more complicated and harder to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong, you should also place `^` and `$` constraints on the first variant:

```
^[^%_#&<>][^#&<>]*|$
```

This because the first case can be applied on a **substring**.

The regex you defined simply states: an empty string, or a string with at least one character that is not `%`, `_`, `#`,...

It think the proposed regex is good enough. Some (probably not java) regex libraries offer additional functionality to state that the string should not contain a certain character. But since the regex is not that complex, it won't help that much.